# WPF: ListBox click and drag selects other items

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox

Simple question:

1) I click and hold the mouse on a ListBoxItem in a ListBox.
2) Now I drag the mouse cursor down over the next ListBoxItem in the list

It now selects this new item. I would like to disable this. So the user has to click an item to select it. Not just drag over it.

I have Single selection turned on.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 3):

This is mostly for the benefit of people like me who still need to know this.

The link majocha provided was the answer, although it's not implemented in a particularly nice way as far as I can see, because it has a hole around the `MouseUp` event and its boolean flag. Why do that when you can just interrogate the `MouseEventArgs` to find out if the button is pressed? Maybe WPF as of 2010 didn't have that capability.

So here's my code for WPF 4. You just have to handle `MouseMove` on the `ListBox` and say this:

```
private void ListBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        (sender as ListBox).ReleaseMouseCapture();
}
```

Tada!

Answer (score 0):

I guess overriding OnPreviewMouseMove will do.
Read [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/0ed8731a-f7b1-4499-9ef9-fc5544fa7007) for similar problem.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give that a try.
The link you provided did not work. Do you have the direct link?

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/0ed8731a-f7b1-4499-9ef9-fc5544fa7007